# Using the Median to Estimate a Parameter

Tags: estimation, inference, median

I am trying to use the Median to estimate the value for the parameter $a$ in the following PMF.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq1:givenpdf}
    \mathbb{P}\left[X=\frac{a}{n}\right] = \frac{36}{5}\frac{n^2}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)\left(n+4\right)}\ for\ n=1,2,\dots
\end{equation}

When equating the CDF to 0.5 to obtain a formula for the median, the following was obtained:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Median}
    \implies \frac{a(5a^2+9an+4n^2)}{5(a+2n)(a+3n)(a+4n)} = 0.5 
\end{equation}
Solving for $n$ yielded:
$$n = -0.3389a - (0.1687 \pm 0.2923i)a + (0.0590 \mp 0.1023i)a \approx (-0.5667 \pm 0.1900i)a$$
$$ \text{and}$$
$$ n= 0.0056 \left[-61a + 60.7433a + 21.2534a \right] \approx 0.1167a$$

For which I chose the real root, for obvious reasons.

How can I use this information to obtain an Estimator for $a$ using the median and apply it on the data set attached below (with is summary statistics)?

I tried researching online, however I am still getting confused because the median for the data set provided is $0.5$

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do those columns in the black table mean? Why do you want to use the median to estimate a? Why is a median of 0.5 confusing you?

Comment: I have to construct an estimator for $a$ and I thought to do that using the Method of Quartiles, specifically the Median. I looked online as to how to do it and cannot understand the procedure.

Then, I have to use the same estimator for the Sample of 100 readings (that in the black box) to obtain an estimate for $a$ of that sample.

Comment: If the use of the Median to obtain an estimator for $a$ cannot be applied here, I am open to trying other methods of estimation, however, I already used the Method of Moments (which gave a unbiased estimator) and the Sample Maximum (biased estimator) as these are what I am familiar with.

Any guidance and help towards finding another estimator (not necessarily using the Median) is appreciated, and if possible some steps to explain the method.

Comment: If the sample size is large (say 100 independent random samples from that distribution), then the maximum $X$ provides usually the exact value of $a$.  That's because with a large sample size the maximum $X$ value is very likely to be $a/1=a$.

Comment: @AustinM You are very close to getting the answer on your own. Rather than solving for $n$, you should be solving for $a$, which gives $a \approx \frac{n}{0.1167}$ where $n$ is the median. This would give you that an estimate for $a$ is about $9$ times the median (which corresponds to the correct answer by @MattF). You made things a bit more complicated than needed for this particular problem, but this approach is good and will work in more general cases.

Comment: Can I assume that your data set is created as 100 random samples with $a=5.5%$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The median of this distribution is at $a/9$, since
$$P[X<\frac{a}9]=48.6\%$$
$$P[X=\frac{a}9]=\ \ 3.4\%$$
$$P[X>\frac{a}9]=48.0\%$$
So you can estimate $a$ as $9$ times the median.

Answer (score 0):

(I've deleted my previous answer as it was a bit sloppy.)

Because in a comment you've mentioned the desire for other estimators, here is an implementation of a maximum likelihood estimator.  Note that this is not so straightforward because potential estimates of $a$ must result in $a/x$ (for any observed value of $X=x$) being a positive integer.

In short for large sample sizes the maximum likelihood estimator will be the maximum of the observed values.  For not-so-large sample sizes the maximum likelihood estimate can be found in the following manner.  Here I've used *Mathematica* but something similar can be produced in R.)  The example below generates data for $a=7.5$.

```
(* Generate a random sample of size 5 *)
p = Table[(36/5) n^2/((n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3) (n + 4)), {n, 1, 10000}];
SeedRandom[12345]; 
nn = RandomChoice[p -> Range[1, 10000], 5]
x = 7.5/nn;  (* Here a = 7.5 *)

(* Find value for a that maximizes the log of the likelihood and 
results in (essentially) all integer values of a/x *)
maxLogL = -Infinity;
mlea =.;
Do[ahat = Max[x]*n; (* Potential estimate of a *)
 ss = (ahat/x - Round[ahat/x])^2 // Total;  (* Distance that ahat/x is from all integers *)
 (* Only attempt to update ahat if ahat/x consists of integers *)
 If[ss < 0.01,
  logL = Total[
    Log[36/5] + 2 Log[ahat] + 2 Log[#] - Log[ahat + #] - 
       Log[ahat + 2 #] - Log[ahat + 3 #] - Log[ahat + 4 #] & /@ x];
  If[logL > maxLogL, mlea = ahat; maxLogL = logL]
  ], {n, 1, 25}]

mlea
(* 7.5 *)

mlea/x  (* Check on mlea/x consists of all integers *)
(* {2, 5, 28, 7, 4} *)
```

Simulations result even for a sample size of 5 in a much, much better estimator than using 9 times the median.

```
SeedRandom[12345]; 
nSimulations = 10000;
mle = ConstantArray[0, nSimulations];
medianEstimator = ConstantArray[0, nSimulations];

Do[
 (* Generate a random sample of size 5 *)
 p = Table[(36/5) n^2/((n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3) (n + 4)), {n, 1, 
    10000}];
 nn = RandomChoice[p -> Range[1, 10000], 5];
 x = 7.5/nn;
 
 (* Median estimator *)
 medianEstimator[[i]] = 9 Median[x];
 
 (* Find value for a that maximizes the log of the likelihood and 
 results in (essentially) all integer values of a/x *)
 maxLogL = -Infinity;
 mlea =.;
 Do[ahat = Max[x]*n; (* Potential estimate of a *)
  ss = (ahat/x - Round[ahat/x])^2 // Total;  (* Distance that ahat/
  x is from all integers *)
  (* Only attempt to update ahat if ahat/x consists of integers *)
  If[ss < 0.01,
   logL = 
    Total[Log[36/5] + 2 Log[ahat] + 2 Log[#] - Log[ahat + #] - 
        Log[ahat + 2 #] - Log[ahat + 3 #] - Log[ahat + 4 #] & /@ x];
   If[logL > maxLogL, mlea = ahat; maxLogL = logL]
   ], {n, 1, 25}];
 mle[[i]] = mlea,
 {i, 1, nSimulations}]
```

Here are the results:

```
{Mean[mle], StandardDeviation[mle], Median[mle]}
(* {7.37627, 0.697574, 7.5} *)

{Mean[medianEstimator], StandardDeviation[medianEstimator], Median[medianEstimator]}
(* {9.09117, 6.764, 7.5} *)
```

A plot of the relative frequencies of estimates for both the maximum likelihood and median estimators:

[image: Relative frequencies of estimates]